# Word denoting place in a row

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Which word or words can be used in order to denote the person standing just before the last person in a row? Is the word **second last** correct in this matter?

Comment: I think it's *second to last.*

Comment: You should add a sentence using your phrase, since the answer may differ based on context.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the word

[**penultimate**](https://www.google.co.jp/#q=penultimate)

> adjective
>
> last but one in a series of things; **second last**.
>
> "the penultimate chapter of the book"

Using 'second last' is not wrong. It'd depend on the reference point to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Second last may be correct in conversational informal English, but the usual phrases both in informal and formal English are:

Second to last, next to last, or last but one.

Comment: *Second last* is apparently British English and *second to last* is American English. This is clarified by looking up *penultimate* in the BrE and AmE versions of Oxford dictionary online.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, "second last" is correct. Although saying "second to last", "next to last", or even "second to the last" **is not incorrect**, it is redundant. It is like saying "second to first" - it has no advantage over saying "second last"

If you would also like to shorten "second last" and/or make this concept less complicated, you can use the word penultimate:

> ### pe·nul·ti·mate
>
> pəˈnəltəmət/
>
> adjective
>
> last but one in a series of things; **second to the last**.
>
> "the penultimate chapter of the book"
>
> synonyms: *next-to-last, second-to-last, second-last*

Comment: Redundant or not, _next/second to last_ are [**more common**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=second+to+last+.%2Csecond+to+the+last+.%2Csecond+last+.%2Cnext+to+last+.%2C+penultimate+.&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csecond%20to%20last%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecond%20to%20the%20last%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecond%20last%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnext%20to%20last%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpenultimate%20.%3B%2Cc0) and more intelligible than _second last_.

Comment: @Fard9 Yes, it is more common and sounds better, but it is redundant. Like I said it's not wrong or better, it's simply redundant.

Comment: It sure is better (or _can_ be better). And come to think of it, it's not even redundant; _second last_ can have other meanings that adding the preposition _to_ puts them out of the picture. Consider: "_Last year, I was picked last in gym; this year you were. I was the first last, and you were the second last_". (We can think of many other examples)

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard anyone say "second last".  I live in the Northeastern US, for what it's worth.  It doesn't even quite make sense to me: last is just *last*; how can something be "second last"?  Can something be "second first"?  (Yes, I know English is not perfectly logical.)  Also, there's nothing "redundant" about the "to", any more than the *to* in "I am going to my house" is "redundant"; it's just the way it's phrased.

Comment: Abob if you are quoting something, you need to include a link to what you are quoting.

Comment: @stangdon *Second last* is apparently British English and *second to last* is American English. This is clarified by looking up *penultimate* in the BrE and AmE versions of Oxford dictionary online. Abob, second to last is not redundant.